# Android app enabled plugins

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, webview

Hy!
I want use flash player in android app. 
If I use the "wSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);" then the eclipse write this:

> The method setPluginsEnabled(boolean) from the type WebSettings is
>   deprecated

Therefore I use this:

```
 wSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

But so not working the flash player.
My code this:

```
package com.exm.be;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings wSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
        wSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
         mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=940rzFtFNbs");
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);  
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed the same message. But even it is deprecated it still works. So in my app I still use  `wSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);`

Answer (score 0):

Add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" to your manifest file.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

Answer (score -1):

> Please check the adobe flash player.

and after that .

mWebView.setFocusable(true);
    mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);